# Discord.js automatic delete message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a question, can you make it so that when you send a message it is automatically deleted (not a command) just a normal message (like hello or good morning) I need this for a channel with text verification

Comment: Yes, you can. Have you tried looking at the DJS and documentation? Just call `.delete()` on the message object

Comment: @Elitezen Can you send an example code please?

Comment: [Message#delete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)

Comment: @Elitezen But how can I use it because you need a command to add it and I want WITHOUT a command so that normal words are deleted

Comment: Just call `.delete()` on the message object emitted by the message event before checking for a command

Comment: Another possible option: You could get the message id and get it through the cache.

Comment: That's not what I meant, there was supposed to be any message written by the user not designated it is so that people could not write there what they want, text verification is already done I just need to add this block because they will be spamming random words!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what [@Elitezen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12464931/elitezen) meant:

```
if (message.content === "whatever you want") {
    message.delete()
}
```

Reference:

[Message#delete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)

Comment: That's not what I meant, there was supposed to be any message written by the user not designated it is so that people could not write there what they want, text verification is already done I just need to add this block because they will be spamming random words!!!

Comment: [TextChannel#awaitMessages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) This could help you perhaps.

Comment: const filter = m => m.content.startsWith('!vote'); commands :C

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/on0xVKf HE CAN SPAM AND MESSAGES DONT DELETE

Comment: If you're looking for a anti spam function you could search it up on the internet, your question wasn't phrased well. Here's a module which can help you with [anti spamming](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-anti-spam).